# Can't make Legend visible in chart

Tags: c#

Hello I'm trying to show a legend in runtime but for some kind of reason it won't show up or the complete size of my chart changes but still I don't see the legend.

Here is the part of the code that draws the Chart

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
 {
 TempDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[0].Value);
     if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(SelectedSpeed))
     {
       //Get vibration values
       yHDE = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

       //Plot Horizontal DE chart
       if (yHDE != 0)
       {
           if (MachineName == newMachineName)
           {
           //Draw the points in the selected series
                          
           this.chartHorizontalDE.Series[MachineName].Points.AddXY(TempDate, yHDE);                                
           }
           else if (MachineName != newMachineName)
           {
           //When a new machine has been selected create a new series name for the chart
           this.chartHorizontalDE.Series.Add(newMachineName);
           this.chartHorizontalDE.Series[newMachineName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                            
           }
       }
   }
   Legend legend = new Legend();
   legend.Docking = Docking.Right;
   chartHorizontalDE.Legends.Add(legend);

}
```

I believe I have all the info in my code and the series for the particular chart should be available. The above last three lines finally gave a result but just changing the size of the chart and I was not able to see the legend. The example on MSDN gave me error that the particular series allready existed btw. I have deleted a big part of the code so maybe I do certain things like it is here is because there is more code but not relevant for the question (I think).

Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: If you want to add a new Legend you need to control ALL of its properties incuding location and size..

Comment: So I'll get this like legend.size, legend.backcolor etc?

Comment: Well, color is not so important, but size may well be. Do use the debugger to explore the properties of your Legend (after you have added it to the ChartArea. Also add at least some Item to it!)

Comment: well there goes my misunderstanding probably I thought I should see items. I expected 3 items. which is in the MachineName series.

Comment: If I try to add items I get the following error:
System.ArgumentException: 'A chart element with the name 'Mach1' could not be found in the 'LegendCollection'.'

Comment: Well didn't you name the new Legend _legend_ ?? And by default the Series LegendItems go into the default Legend. . Maybe you can find some examples in my [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+legend)